# How can I get a function to check if a property is disabled?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get my function to check if a field is disabled, and if so put a border around it. I have the following code:
HTML

```
<br />

<input id="input1" disabled/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">
Button
</button>
```

Script:

```
   function myFunction() {
         var confirmPassword = $("#input1").val();
          if (confirmPassword.prop('disabled')){
          alert("disabled");
          } else {
                        alert("enabled");
         }
     }
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/4vn5kemo/

Comment: just remove `.val()` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update from

```
var confirmPassword = $("#input1").val();
```

to

```
var confirmPassword = $("#input1");
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/JXN2ZU0PRNq7vgLvDeSl

```js
 function myFunction() {
         var confirmPassword = $("#input1");
          if (confirmPassword.prop('disabled')){
          alert("disabled");
          } else {
                        alert("enabled");
         }
     }
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <input id="input1" disabled/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">
Button
</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Stacker - Please check the plunker shared in answer.

Comment: thanks, not sure why I couldn't get it working on fiddle

Comment: @Stacker - Here is your fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/4vn5kemo/3/. You did not add jquery (external resource) and fiddle was not able to find the function. You can check console for errors. Hope it helps.